# A linear transformation which maps the unit sphere to itself.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A \colon\Bbb  R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ is a linear transformation which maps the unit sphere to itself.
Then $A$ is

a) symmetric;

b) orthogonal;

c) positive definite;

d) symmetric and positive definite.

By the given condition my intuition says $\|Ax\|=\|x\|$  so $A$ will be orthogonal transformation. it may have negative eigenvalue so it will not be positive definite. Its characteristic polynomial will be of degree three and may have a complex root, so in that case it will not be symmetric as symm matricx has eigen value only realss. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Notice that $\displaystyle \left\|A \cdot \frac{x}{\|x\|} \right\|=1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}$. For the other points, you can think about rotations.